# How to place contents in the middle of viewport in case of xs devices using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

For my blog, I want to place every content (image and text)in the middle of viewport in case of xs devices only. I am new to bootstrap and i do not know how to overcome this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

                    <a href="donate.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/help-1.jpg" style=" box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);"></a>
                    <pOur Recent Update</p><br>

                    <a href="#recentUpadePage">################<img src="images/new12.gif"></a><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

                <div id="slider">
                    <figure>
                    <img src="images/helpUs1.jpg" alt="help">
                    <img src="images/helpUs2.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="images/helpUs3.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="images/helpUs4.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="images/helpUs5.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <p id="heading">Image Gallery</p><br>
                    <a href="gallery.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery.jpg" style=" box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 5px 5px 5px;"></a>

                    <p id="heading">Message </p><br>

            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class active only for mobile devices like

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    .active_on_xs_device{
         text-align:center !important;
    }

    .active_on_xs_device_img{
         display:block !important;
         margin-left: auto !important;
         margin-right:auto !important;
    }

}
```

Add the image class for only images

Comment: Did you add the first class(with text-align: center) to the container div?

Comment: it will work only for texts only but i want it for images too.

Comment: If i add margin left and margin right as a inline style to <img> tag then its work fine, but if i add media rules it does not works.